# wso2 Getting token for invalid credentials for password grant

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2, wso2-identity-server, wso2-esb

I am using the combination of WSO2 API Manager and WSO2 identity server and configured using the following documentation
https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER44x/Configuring+the+Pre-Packaged+Identity+Server+5.2.0+with+API+Manager+2.0.0

In this case ,WSO2 idenity server acts as key manager and API Manager manages scopes.

I have configured and its working.
I tried to use the password grant and its giving me a bearer token even if i hit with wrong username and password.It feels as if its only checking the client id which i pass in the url.

```
curl -X POST \
  https://mycustomwsourl.in:9443/oauth2/token \
  -H 'authorization: Basic TnVMb0tGRmJlZ3hqUThNeW5uYzlHWmE1bkpBYTpKSzRINmp5M3V4Zl8wNFZNX25lbDhncnJwMm9h' \
  -H 'content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
  -H 'grant_type: password' \
  -H 'password: testuser' \ 
  -H 'scope: SCOPE_EDIT SCOPE_READ SCOPE_REMOVE' \
  -H 'username: testuser'
```

If i pass a client code differently it throws me an error. Otherwise it gives back bearer token always.

Can it be because identity server is not acting as key manager? any configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is very strange. It should actually send an error message because you're sending `grant_type` as a header which is wrong. All these data should be sent in the POST body like this.

```
curl -k -d "grant_type=password&username=<username>&password=<password>" -H "Authorization: Basic d1U2MkRqbHlEQm5xODdHbEJ3cGxmcXZtQWJBYTprc2RTZG9lZkREUDd3cGFFbGZxdm1qRHVl" -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" https://localhost:8243/token
```

Reference: https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM200/Password+Grant

Comment: Let me try with a simple curl. I just generated the curl from our application. May be something wrong with the code.
Thank for the tip that it should be POST body

Comment: What is the significance of port 8243? Which service listens to this port?

Comment: `:8243/token` is the proxy API in apim which fronts identity server's `:9443/oauth2/token`. You should use the former always.

Comment: some how 8243 is not accessible.is it the one in the axis\s.xml?

Should i have to change any thing below to make this work? I have a custom domain name
<transportReceiver name="https" class="org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSSLListener">
        <parameter name="port" locked="false">8243</parameter>
        <parameter name="non-blocking" locked="false">true</parameter>
        <!--parameter name="bind-address" locked="false">hostname or IP address</parameter-->
        <!--parameter name="WSDLEPRPrefix" locked="false">https://apachehost:port/somepath</parameter

Comment: In IS as KM pack, 8243 (synapse transport) port is not available. It's open in APIM only. So if you follow documentation properly, APIM gateway's `:8243/token` api should front key manager's `:9443/oauth2/token` api.